# How can i update specific records using a looped drop down list where its records are from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, loops, select

So here's the thing, I want to make a simple page or module that will update the quantity of a certain product in my inventory but the items are listed already on a drop down list(select tag) where its elements are from my records in the database so the user can only update products that is IN the database.

Here's my code:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * from inventory order by item_name");
$ctr=0;
while($inventory=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$print=$inventory['item_name'];
$cquantity=$inventory['quantity'];
$selected=array();
$selected[$ctr]=$print;
?>


<option value="<?php echo "$selected[$ctr]";?>"> <?php echo $print; ?></option>
<?php $ctr++;}

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$add=$_POST['add'];
$subtract=$_POST['subtract'];
if ($add>0)
{
$quantity=$cquantity+$add;
$sql="Update inventory set quantity='$quantity' where item_name='$selected[$ctr]'";
mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
?>


<script>
alert("Inventory was successfully updated.");
</script>

<?php
}
else{
echo "<font color='red'>Please fill up the form correctly.</font>";}
if ($subtract>0)
{
$quantity=$cquantity-$subtract;
$sql="Update inventory set quantity='$quantity' where item_name='$selected[$ctr]'";
mysql_query($sql);
?>
<script>
alert("Inventory was successfully updated.");
</script>
<?php
}
else {echo "<font color='red'>Please fill up the form correctly.</font>";}
}
```

?>

I know that my problem is in the SQL command: 
    `$sql="Update inventory set quantity='$quantity' where item_name='$selected[$ctr]'";` 
because ctr will be incremented at the last part of the loop.

How will I make a right sql code that will make the where clause recognize the value or name of the selected data in the drop down list?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. I was thinking too much deep, I didn't notice that all i have to do is to assign a variable and set its value to the posted value of my `<select>` and that's all.